# C# CancellationToken Saved in Local Storage

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am converting CancellationToken class to binary so I can save it on local storage for use in future as the thread will be continuous when I convert it back, will it still function in the same manner and cancel the task in question?

First I launch the Task using the token I initialized, I then store it in the db using the ObjectToBinary function. The code below shows how I am trying to cancel the Token.

If this is not possible, does anyone have an alternative solution to my problem?

```
    public static async Task StopAccountRunning(int fid)
    {
        using (gg db = new gg())
        {
            var acc = db.FInfos.FirstOrDefault(account => account.Fid == fid);
            var token = BinaryToObject<CancellationToken>(acc.ProcessCancellationToken, true);
            var tokenSrc = BinaryToObject<CancellationTokenSource>(acc.ProcessCancellationSource);

            if(token.CanBeCanceled)
            {
                tokenSrc.Cancel();
            }
            acc.isAccountRunning = 0;

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    public static T BinaryToObject<T>(byte[] data) where T : class
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream s = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(s);
        }
    }

    public static T BinaryToObject<T>(byte[] data, bool isStruct) where T : struct
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream s = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(s);
        }
    }

    public async static Task<byte[]> ObjectToBinary<T>(T data)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(s, data);
            bytes = s.ToArray();
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: It shouldn't work. I recommend showing your code.

Comment: No it won't work. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @John Code has been updated

Comment: As far as I know, this will not work, as _cancelation_ is done just by invoking specific event inside specific object (cancellation token). So, when you deserialize him - it is brand new (and lonely) cancelation token, and no other object or Task one know about him:(

Comment: `I have not tested` Give it a test. Did it work?

Comment: @vasily.sib Do you have an alternative solution or anything I should look into to solve the problem I am trying to solve?

Comment: Well, there is a lot of solutions. It's just not clear what are you trying to do. Are this is some sort of scheduler? Why do your tasks runs so long?

Comment: @vasily.sib It's a complicated service tbh but I run thousands of tasks beside eachother that just continuously run but I need a method to be able to Cancel them at any time.

Comment: Then one way is to do this is to store cancelation token sources objects (not serialized) in some kind of store by some generated Id (GUID for ex.), and store this Id in DB, so you can retrive this object later by something like `store[acc.ProcessCancellationTokenId].Cancel()`. Another way is to run each task in separate process and store this process Id. Then you can "cancel" this process by `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(acc.ProcessId).Kill()`

Comment: you trying to do something with specific parameters, for example, you are trying to calculate all employees and you want to calculate every member in the separate thread and you want to get the last state of each employee if any of them got some exceptions and continue from the last state am I Right?

Comment: @AlirezaYadegari No, I would just like to stop the task after I have left it run but I need a method for aborting the task.

Comment: @vasily.sib Do you have anything I could read about the first option? I am creating MVC 5 Website any user can launch the task but I need to be able to also cancel the task. I was thinking of global variable but just need to make sure it will function the way I am looking for.

Comment: @Aidan during your task you just can use 'return' in your main method and the task find out its responsibility is done and it reaches to await in your main method

Comment: @Aidan, if you on MVC and have some sort of DI, you can just use a "singleton service"